# Changing array values in PHP

Tags: php, array

I need to change some array values in a 2-dimensional array for some cases. Sometimes the all values from an child array and sometimes only some values.
In this cases I should only change the variable `$stamm` which `$stamm2`.

This code is the statement of an if condition, where all relevant verbs for this changings  is mentioned.

`$verb` could be one over 25.000 french verbs. For this example you could use 'acheter'.

```
  $array = array( 
  array('e', 'es', 'e', 'ons', 'ez', 'ent'), array('ais', 'ais', 'ait', 'ions', 'iez', 'aient'), array('ai', 'as', 'a', 'âmes', 'âtes', 'èrent'), array('erai', 'eras', 'era', 'erons', 'erez', 'eront'), array('e', 'es', 'e', 'ions', 'iez', 'ent'), array('asse', 'asses', 'ât', 'assions', 'assiez', 'assent'), array('erais', 'erais', 'erait', 'erions', 'eriez', 'eraient'), array('e', 'ons', 'ez'), array('XXX'), array('ant'));
```

My short old code:

> ```
> $stamm = substr("$verb", 0, - 2);    
> $stamm2 = substr_replace($stamm, '<u>è</u>', -2, 1);
>
> $array[0][0] = $array[0][2] = $array[4][0] = $array[4][2] = $array[7][0] = $stamm2.'e';
> $array[0][1] = $array[4][1] = $stamm2.'es';
> $array[0][5] = $array[4][5] = $stamm2.'ent';
> ```

My new improved code:

```
$stamm = substr("$verb", 0, - 2);    
$stamm2 = substr_replace($stamm, '<u>è</u>', -2, 1);

$zeiten = array(0, 3, 4, 6, 7);        
foreach($zeiten as $zeit) { 
    foreach($array[$zeit] as $person => $value) {               
        if ((($zeit == 0  || $zeit == 4) && !in_array($person,array(3,4))) || ($zeit == 3 || $zeit == 6) || ($zeit == 7 && $person==0)) 
        $array[$zeit][$person] = str_replace($stamm, $stamm2, $value);      
        }   
    }
```

Is this the the new code the best solution? Is it possible to improve the if condition?

Comment: Please provide a more context on the problem you are trying to solve and what values are in `$array`, `$stamm` and `$stamm2`.

Comment: @Nobody I have edited my question.

Comment: It is still missing the variable `$array`. To make it more clear: Preferably your code should be runnable as is. As far as I can see you should provide example values for `$array` and `$verb` and would be fine.

Comment: @Nobody Their is also an array_walk function to combine `$array` and `$stamm`. The code is workung for both versions.

Comment: You are still  missing an example value for `$verb` and the overall description of what you are trying to do. My assumption is: You are trying to build a function that gives all possible inflections of a given verb according to french language. Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24657/discussion-between-grischa-and-nobody).

Answer (score 7):

Let me first review this from an readability point of view, then answer your question and an proposed solution.

## Naming

Your variable names could be more descriptive.

- `$array` -> (maybe) `$conjugations` (german: `$konjugationen`)
- `$stamm` -> `$word_stem` (german: `$wort_stamm`)
- `$zeiten` -> `$tenses` (german: `$zeitformen`)?

## Structure

The most intriguing part for me is `$array`'s structure.
As I understand it, it is a 2D table of conjugations of the `$verb` where rows have the same tense and columns the same person. This should be somehow reflected in the data structure because it is not obvious to the viewer.
Maybe you should even implement a class for that.

## Comparison

Maybe it has to do with my lack of domain knowledge (I don't speak french) but I find both solutions unreadable.
This is enforced by the naming problems.

The second one looks slightly more general with regard to reuse but the `if` portion is not very flexible.

## Improvement

As I said, I have no idea about french but I suppose this holds true:

Each verb can be conjugated for person and tense. There is a set of rules that defines how this happens for each person and tense depending on the verb's form and a set of exemptions from those rules.

The solution to the problem consists of:

1. Classifying the verb as to which rule/exemption to apply
2. applying the rule

To me this sounds like 1. could be solved by a factory that creates strategy instances for 2.

```
$conjugator = get_conjugator($verb, $tense, $person);
$conjugated_verb = $conjugator->conjugate($verb);
```

Maybe the exceptions/rules are even partial per tense or person. This would mean you would have to make this distinction as well and produce a separate conjugator for each tense, person, verb triple.

Now the code you have posted is pretty much the part that goes into the implementation of a conjugator. And seeing that there could be many of them it would be nice to make implementing them as simple as possible.

Their interface would probably consist of a function that detects whether they are applicable (the `if` condition in your case) and a function that does the actual flexion of the input (the `if`'s then code block).

Comment: I would even go as far to suggest that OP implement a Trie data structure. It is perfect for this.

Comment: @EvanBechtol: I am not sure if it is a pure string matching problem. It probably is more complex.

Comment: This would however be a really nice usecase for a Trie. Good review!

Comment: @Nobody I have  a long time nothing to hear from you. Maybe you have now a little bit time to finish the conjugation script together.

Comment: @Grischa: I am still swamped with work but I hope to have more time available soon. I will contact you when I am available.

Comment: @Grischa: Finally I have time to go on. When do you have time to continue? I would propose we use [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37043/french-conjugation).

Comment: @Nobody I will try to have time, when you have time. It would be sooo great to finish the script, so I could use it for other languages.